# add a JDateChooser in jTable cell and get The Value from the cell

Tags: java

When i add the JDAteChooser in jtable cell it work verry well but when i start adding date withe jDatechooser he put de date withe this format "2016-12-31  Sun Dec 18 11:33:56 WAT 2016", i want it withe this format YYYY-MM-dd
this my JDateChooserCellEditor.

```
package Acteur;
import com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.swing.AbstractCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.event.CellEditorListener;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;

/**
 * A CellEditor for tables, using a JDateChooser.
 * 
 * @author Kai Toedter
 * @version $LastChangedRevision: 100 $
 * @version $LastChangedDate: 2006-06-04 14:36:06 +0200 (So, 04 Jun 2006) $
 */
public class JDateChooserCellEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements
        TableCellEditor {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 917881575221755609L;

    private JDateChooser dateChooser = new JDateChooser();



    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
            System.out.println("HICEM"+this.getCellEditorValue());

        return dateChooser;
}

        @Override
    public Date getCellEditorValue() {
        return dateChooser.getDate();
    }
}
```

And i call it here :

```
 public AlerteCarte() {

    initComponents();
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) Table.getTable().getModel();
    this.jTable1.setModel(model);
    TableColumn column1 = jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(3);
    //column1.setCellRenderer( new JDateChooserRenderer());
    column1.setCellEditor(new JDateChooserCellEditor());

    TableColumn column2 = jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(2);
    //column2.setCellRenderer( new JDateChooserRenderer());
    column2.setCellEditor(new JDateChooserCellEditor());
    jTable1.setRowHeight(30);
    jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(100);
    jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(100);

}
```

Comment: pleasse i need help